# Google Sheets Array Formula Doesn't apply to the rest of the Column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas

I currently have a sheet that is pulling data from a Google Form. Whenever new data is entered through the form I want this formula to automatically calculate. However it will not apply to the entire column and only the first row that I enter it in.

This is the formula

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(D2), "",1-((COUNTIFS(BH:BH, BH3, D:D, "Unavailable")) + (COUNTIFS(BH:BH, BH3, D:D, "Stage*")))/32))`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm I got it. It should be ISBLANK(D2:D)...

Comment: We can't see what you're looking at. But it seems to me that if you are using `D2:D` in the opening `IF` function, you also need to adjust instances of `BH:BH` and `D:D` to read `BH2:BH` and `D2:D` respectively or everything will be one off.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(D2:D="",,1-(
 (COUNTIFS(BH:BH, BH3, D:D, "Unavailable"))+ 
 (COUNTIFS(BH:BH, BH3, D:D, "Stage*")))/32))
```